# Running full node. Why is chaindata folder > 300GB?

Tags: blockchain, nodes

I'm running a full node with Mist and my chaindata folder is huge. It's over 300GB when the block-chain is currently just over 100GB. There's over 169,000 files. Is that normal?

Is there a way to recover what I already have instead of just deleting it all and re-syncing?

Comment: 300GB is huge, the solutions I know of is just to delete chaindata folder and re-sync it with --fast. I'm also looking for another way of doing it

Comment: If I want to run a full node, I shouldn't use --fast, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, have to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just deleting the contents of the chaindata folder and re-sycing a full node and it only took 11 hours; 16,700 files and only 33 GB. There was definitely something wrong with the old chaindata. Previously, it took me 12 hrs to sync 1 day of transactions. Now, its so much faster.

Comment: How large is your block size and the chain structure you downloaded? Mine has been downloading for over a couple days now. I am currently stuck on Block 4,448,214/4,550,977 since more than 15 hours and the chain structure is 20,000,000+ / increasing every now and then.. 12 hours ago I was at 14,000,000+ . My chaindata folder is 31,150 Mb (15803 files) so I'm guessing I still have 1k files at least to go... I'm running Mist (Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-9-2)

Comment: I ended up on selecting the light client sync as suggested [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2466#issuecomment-332944833) Synchronized in a matter of minutes.